# django: multiple db and contenttype

Tags: django

I am creating a Django project with one app called 'db_manager'. I would like to create two db: one for the db_manager models, and one for the core django models (auth, admin, contentTypes, session...)

First, I run the migrations to create the core models in the adw_core db. Then, I run the migrations to create the db_manager models in the adw_facts db. I use this command:
`python manage.py migrate db_manager --database adw_facts`

I have a router set up that directs app to the appropriate db:

settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['data_warehouse.db_routers.DatabaseRouter']

MAP_APPS_TO_DB = {
    'db_manager': 'adw_facts',
    'django.contrib.auth': 'adw_core',
    'django.contrib.sessions': 'adw_core',
}
```

db_routers.py

```
class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB:
            return settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB:
            return settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        # Allow any relation between apps that use the same database.
        db_obj1 = settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
        db_obj2 = settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
        if db_obj1 and db_obj2:
            if db_obj1 == db_obj2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB:
            return db == settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB[app_label]
        return None
```

When I run the migrations to create the db_manager models in the adw_facts db, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.`

I confirm that  table 'core_db.django_content_type' exists. The problem must be that the `django.contrib.contenttypes` app is trying to create contentTypes for db_manager in adw_facts db but table core_db.django_content_type is in the adw_core db.

I don't want to delete the contenttypes app because I am using it with other Django functionalities.

I can think of the following solutions:

1. disable contenttypes for the facts models
2. create a secnod contenttypes table for the facts_db

Neither of these is very appealing. Please let me know if you have a better solution.

Comment: Maybe your have a good reason for such separation, but if you ever would want to add userid field to one of your models or leverage user permissions there will be issues, as Django currently doesn't support cross db joins.

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to get the sense that this is not the right way to go, as Django doesn't support this feature very well. There should be a warning in the docs.

Comment: @Nico - There is a warning regarding the [limitations of multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases) in the current Django documentation. I don't know how long it has been there.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I want to create a Model in another database, not planning any relationship with other models from the main database, however, the ContentType relationship is mandatory, and overcome this problem is something I didn't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 8):

Just faced the same issue (on django 2.1).
Based on the documentation mentioned by @Tony, it seems that you need to duplicate data from several django components in each database.
Here's what worked for me:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label in ('sites', 'contenttypes', 'auth'):
        return True

    if app_label in settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB:
        return db == settings.MAP_APPS_TO_DB[app_label]
    return None
```

Comment: Thanks for offering a solution. I'm too far from the problem now to confirm whether this fixes the problem I was having. If others confirm that this helps, I'm happy to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I can confirm that adding the condition to always return `True` for `sites`, `contenttypes`, and `auth` to the `allow_migrate` method of the router as demonstrated above worked to solve this issue for me.